# How to get the screen space coordinate from the widget local coordinates

Tags: qt, qt5

This is the code where i am getting the mouse position coordinates local to a widget.

```
        QPoint relativeMousePos = QCursor::pos();
        QPoint point = widgetRender->mapFromGlobal(relativeMousePos);
```

This means that my widget with the size of 920 X 517 and if I click on the left corner the value received is (0.0 , 0.0)

For the left corner the value is (920.0 , 517.0)

How can i convert this to screen space coordinates.

If i click on the left corner the value returned should be (0.0 , 0.0 )But for the right corner instead of (920.0 , 517.0) the value should be (1920 X 1080) which is the screen resoultion.

Answer (score 1):

```
QPoint relativeMousePos = QCursor::pos();
QPoint point = widgetRender->mapFromGlobal(relativeMousePos);

int screenX = point.x() * 1920 /  widgetRender->width();
int screenY = point.y() * 1080 /  widgetRender->height();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , i wanted to know does Qwidget offer any function like that.